# Spring boot return application/pdf with a ResponseEntity<Resource>

Tags: rest, spring-boot, pdf

In my springboot application, I try to return a pdf file with a ResponseEntity-Resource- to mock a service. So I can't change the return type of this method.

My code :

```
@RequestMapping(
        value = "/pdf",
        produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,
        method = RequestMethod.GET
)
public ResponseEntity<Resource> getpdf() {
    try {
        ClassPathResource pdfFile = new ClassPathResource("sample.pdf");

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_ORIGIN, "*");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_METHODS, "GET, POST, PUT");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.ACCESS_CONTROL_ALLOW_HEADERS, "Content-Type");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CACHE_CONTROL, "no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.PRAGMA, "no-cache");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.EXPIRES, "0");
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_DISPOSITION, "attachment;filename=" + pdfFile.getFilename());
        headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);

        log.info("pdfFile.contentLength() : " + pdfFile.contentLength());

        return ResponseEntity
                .ok()
                .headers(headers)
                //.contentLength(pdfFile.contentLength())
                //.contentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF)
                .body(new InputStreamResource(pdfFile.getInputStream()));
    } catch (IOException e) {
        log.error("Couldn't serialize response for content type ", e);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
    }
}
```

When I try to call this get with postman or swagger I have a 406 with response header :

```
{   
"date": "Fri, 02 Nov 2018 14:04:44 GMT",   
"content-length": "0", 
"content-type": null 
}
```

Does anyone have an idea?

[Swagger response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xqvA.png)

Answer (score 3):

way too complex.. downloading a file is much more easy

```
@GetMapping(value="printing/",produces= MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE)
public  @ResponseBody byte[]  print(@RequestParam("filterParam") String filterParam) {

    try {
        FileInputStream fis= new FileInputStream(new File("path to your file"));
        byte[] targetArray = new byte[fis.available()];
        fis.read(targetArray);
        return targetArray;
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can remove `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE`.

There is no need to add `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE,` in RequestMapping as it seems to try to convert the ResponeBody internally.

Below line of code is enough which you are already using.

```
headers.add(HttpHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE, MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE);
```

Comment: I already try without `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE` and I have a 406 too but with different return message :

    Response Body
    {
      "timestamp": "2018-11-02T14:36:21.094Z",
      "status": 406,
      "error": "Not Acceptable",
      "message": "Could not find acceptable representation",
      "path": "/pdfs"
    }

[Swagger Response without application/pdf][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/4vNkw.png


With `produces = MediaType.APPLICATION_PDF_VALUE` :

    Response Body
    [object Blob]